# Команда WSL не существует

Tags: wsl

Я впервые скачал **Docker**, и он застрял в бесконечной загрузке. В ответах *надо было ввести команды wsl.* Я ввел их в PowerShell - `ошибка`, только потом я смог попасть туда, но там тоже самое что на самом wsl. Захожу в Ubuntu (WSL), пишу, он говорит что *нет такой команды*, но можно скачать пакет wsl. скачал, ничего не работает.

> Что делать?

Comment: Скачать `WSL` мало, нужно его ещё поставить ) Больше подробностей нужно

Comment: @CrazyElf , не могли бы рассказать как его поставить? (уже добавил подсистему для Linux, скачал Ubuntu, поставил логин и пароль)

Comment: Что именно вы пытаетесь вводить? wsl - не команда, а название подсистемы.

Comment: @AlexU Я сам ещё не очень разбираюсь, смотрел какие-то видео на ютьюбе и руководства, с трудом тоже поставил, но даже и без линуксов, чисто один WSL. Вы добавьте в вопрос подробности - что вы запускаете, что получается, скриншоты какие-то. Мало информации.

Comment: @CrazyElf , да это я _тупой_. Я писал это в ```PowerShell```, а там надо писать **.\Название.exe**, а я просто писал ```wsl``` и команду, а так - можно только в **самом wsl** и ```cmd```.

Comment: @insolor , я писал wsl и дальше команду, которая подсистема должна была выполнить. Но я уже разобрался что к чему.